# Undefined reference to C++ variables in ASM code

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile following asm code inside a C++ file, but it like GCC can't find the variables used in the asm part.

```
DWORD d_eaxSave, d_ebxSave, d_ecxSave, d_edxSave, d_esiSave, d_ediSave, d_espSave, d_ebpSave;

#define ASM_UNPREFIXED_INTEL_START ".intel_syntax noprefix\n\t"
#define SAVE_REGISTERS() __asm__ (ASM_UNPREFIXED_INTEL_START    \
                              "mov d_eaxSave, eax\n\t"      \
                              "mov d_ebxSave, ebx\n\t"      \
                              "mov d_ecxSave, ecx\n\t"      \
                              "mov d_edxSave, edx\n\t"      \
                              "mov d_esiSave, esi\n\t"      \
                              "mov d_ediSave, edi\n\t"      \
                              "mov d_espSave, esp\n\t"      \
                              "mov d_ebpSave, ebp");
```

But when I try to compile, GCC gives me the following errors :

```
undefined reference to `d_eaxSave'
undefined reference to `d_ebxSave'
undefined reference to `d_ecxSave'
undefined reference to `d_edxSave'
undefined reference to `d_esiSave'
undefined reference to `d_ediSave'
undefined reference to `d_espSave'
undefined reference to `d_ebpSave'
```

What can I do to get rid of those erros, please ?

Comment: that duplicate is not very good in general case...

Comment: The question is a duplicate, but the answers to the other question are all wrong. You should use output parameters as given Antti Haapala's answer here.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. But it doesn't matter that it's been closed, because Antti Haapala has already asnwered it.

Comment: Well, indeed this is not exactly a duplicate, as the other one was about global variables in C and this is about C++; as the variables have C++ linkage here so nothing in there can work here direct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to generally use the AT&T syntax, because as far as I know, GCC cannot emit proper [intel syntax in inline assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347909/can-i-use-intel-syntax-of-x86-assembly-with-gcc) without `-masm=intel` command line switch for everything - I'd presume then you cannot include *any* header files that would use AT&T inline assembly.

Thus:

```
DWORD d_eaxSave, d_ebxSave, d_ecxSave, d_edxSave, d_esiSave, d_ediSave, d_espSave, d_ebpSave;

#define SAVE_REGISTERS() __asm__ __volatile__(         \
     "movl %%eax, %0\n\t"      \
     "movl %%ebx, %1\n\t"      \
     "movl %%ecx, %2\n\t"      \
     "movl %%edx, %3\n\t"      \
     "movl %%esi, %4\n\t"      \
     "movl %%edi, %5\n\t"      \
     "movl %%esp, %6\n\t"      \
     "movl %%ebp, %7":         \
     "=m"(d_eaxSave), "=m"(d_ebxSave), "=m"(d_ecxSave), "=m"(d_edxSave),  \
     "=m"(d_esiSave), "=m"(d_ediSave), "=m"(d_espSave), "=m"(d_ebpSave)   \
)
```

The symbols might not exist for the assembler, so you need to use them via output parameters!
Note also, that generally you would want to use `__volatile__` to make sure that the assembler block is not optimized away.

Comment: That why the OP has a `.intel_syntax noprefix` directive, but he probably needs to add a `.att_syntax prefix` at the end to set it back.  But that's independent of using the output parameters which is the real (and correct) answer to the question.

Comment: Nope, the `.intel_syntax noprefix` did not make GCC emit Intel syntax output parameters; and if the whole file needs to be compiled using `.intel_syntax` anyways, there is no point in changing the syntaxes. Also if this is in a header file, it will cause a major nuisance if any other files with inline assembler are used.

Comment: This is the way to go (except that I would omit the trailing semicolon). Unfortunately, you need a doctorate in compiler architecture to use the GCC in-line assembler with any confidence.

Comment: Removed the semicolon; I do not have a doctorate, nor a CS degree of any kind, so I do not have that much confidence, but I did write a 32-bit protected mode kernel in C++ and inline GAS, and the kernel even occasionally works, so.