# GCC: Error: junk `:0x+57f120' after expression

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, compiler-errors

Following my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041658/undefined-reference-to-c-variables-in-asm-code/), I have now a "error junk after expression" when the compiler try to compile the following code:

```
u32 jmpAdd = BW::BWFXN_SpendRepairReturnAddress;
//BW::BWFXN_SpendRepairReturnAddress has the following value: 0x0046700D
__asm__ __volatile__
(
    "movl ds:0x+57f120(, %eax, 4), %ecx\n\t"
    "jmp %0":"=m"(jmpAdd)
);
```

GCC gives me the following errors:

```
Error: junk ':0x+57f120' after expression
Error: invalid instruction suffix for 'jmp'
```

How can I correct those errors, please?

EDIT: the original code was the following (I converted it using ta2as v0.8.2) :

```
__asm
{
  mov ecx, dword ptr ds:[eax*4+0x57f120]
  jmp BW::BWFXN_SpendRepairReturnAddress
}
```

Comment: ta2as is converting the syntax to AT&T syntax alright, but not necessarily into the proper format for inline assembly in GCC. I recommend the following two guides: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html and http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly

Comment: "0x+57f120" doesn't look like a valid hex literal to me, but I'm not well versed in gcc assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to the following and it should compile:

```
__asm__ __volatile__
(
    "movl %%ds:0x57f120(, %%eax, 4), %%ecx\n\t"
    "jmp *%0" : : "m"(jmpAdd)
);
```

Unfortunately, after looking at the [source](http://bwapi.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3969/trunk/bwapi/BWAPI/Source/Assembly.cpp) you're probably trying to convert it won't actually work. GCC doesn't support `naked` functions on x86 targets.