# How to use Intel x86 inline assembly instead of AT&T

Tags: c++, eclipse, assembly, x86, att

I'm on a Windows machine and by default due to Cygwin I have AT&T assembly directives and would like to switch over to using Intel. I've been using Eclipse to write C++ code.

I added a `.gdbinit` to my `$HOME` with `set disassembly-flavor intel` as the only text inside of it.
I then restarted Eclipse and yet when I come back and try:

```
asm(
    "mov eax, 1"
);
```

I get the following error: `Error: too many memory references for 'mov'`

Now if I change it back to AT&T syntax like so:

```
asm(
    "movl $1, %eax"
);
```

Then everything works fine.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Is this the question you are asking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347909/can-i-use-intel-syntax-of-x86-assembly-with-gcc

Comment: @zch ugggh you're right. I added `-masm=intel` from command line but forgot to add it to eclipse. Not sure how to close a question....

Comment: why not write up your solution as answer instead.