# x64 assembler for system programming

Tags: assembly

I want to do system programming, and I need assembly for some of the stuff I am going to do. The problem is, I cannot find an assembler for a 64-bit computer. I have tried TASM and NASM. With TASM, it won't let me assemble anything, and with NASM, the resulting executable says it's not compatible with my computer. Is there any other assemblers I can use? (I do not want to use one that requires AT&T syntax)

Comment: The GNU assembler offers to use intel syntax as well. You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347909/can-i-use-intel-syntax-of-x86-assembly-with-gcc

Comment: `nasm` should work fine, you are doing something wrong. I am guessing you used wrong output format or forgot to link...

Comment: There is also [fasm](http://flatassembler.net/).

Comment: Both `yasm` and `nasm` as well as `as` (gas) work fine for x86_64. Make sure you are compiling for the correct architecture.

Answer (score 2):

If you were using Linux x86_64

```
$ nasm -f elf -g -F stabs FOO.asm 
$ ld -o FOO FOO.o -melf_i386
```

produces a 32 bit file which can run on 32 bit or 64 bit computer.
`$` is the command line prompt for the Linux OS "bash" console. (FOO is an example file name)

```
$ nasm -f elf64 -g -F stabs FOO.asm 
$ ld -o FOO FOO.o
```

produces a 64 bit executable again for the Linux OS. MS windows would use a different 
command like win32 or win64 in place of elf or elf64, for example.

```
$nasm -hf
```

will give you more info.
Sorry, I dumped Windows for Linux 15 years ago.
I'm just an assembly beginner myself, so this is about all I can offer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running windows, Visual Studio Express (which is free) includes ml64.exe, a 64 bit assembler. A custom build step is needed to invoke ml64.exe, which I think you'll get prompted for the first time you try this, but I create the step manually. I first create an empty project, then choose project, properties, configuration manager, < new >, and select x64 to produce a 64 bit executable. For the custom build step

For debug build:

```
Command Line:
ml64 /c /Zi /Fo$(OutDir)\example.obj example.asm

Outputs:
$(OutDir)\example.obj
```

For release build:

```
Command Line:
ml64 /c /Fo$(OutDir)\example.obj example.asm

Outputs:
$(OutDir)\example.obj
```