# GNU/x86 equilavent for intel assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, att

I am new with assembly. Trying to port the assembly written in Intel syntax to X86 assembly syntax. I am done with almost all the required statements.
But can't find any way to port the below call in Intel Syntax

```
call [ebp+16]
```

to X86 assembly syntax. Based on google I get the below statement for x86

```
call label
```

Is it possible to do something like "call 16(%ebp)" in X86 assembly? If so what are the ways to do so?

Comment: That syntax should work, although it does give a warning. Indirect calls/jumps should have a `*`, so `call *16(%ebp)`.

Comment: Your trying to convert from x86 Intel syntax to x86 AT&T syntax.

Comment: Also note that most GNU tools can be switched to intel syntax, and that you can convert between syntaxes if you assemble using one and disassemble using the other.

Comment: Since, I think, gcc 2.10 you can also just use the [`.intel_syntax`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html#i386_002dVariations) directive

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9347957/327083

Comment: Thanks for all the reply. I was getting an error "unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix". The solution given by Jester solved the issue.

Comment: Can't you just use YASM or NASM?  GNU `as` with `.intel_syntax` still uses gas-style assembler directives, not full NASM syntax.