# Error when using GAS with .intel_syntax

Tags: linux, assembly, compiler-errors, intel, att

According to some documentation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9347957/2501622), it is possible to use GAS in Linux with the Intel syntax instead of the default AT&T syntax.

I tried to compile the following simple code, contained in a dedicated file `file.s`:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

section .data

section .text
        global _start

_start:
        mov eax, 1      # some random comments

        mov ebx, 0      

        int 80h
```

If I run `as file.s -o file.o`, the following error is produced:

```
is2_exit.s: Assembler messages:
is2_exit.s:3: Error: no such instruction: `section .data'
is2_exit.s:5: Error: no such instruction: `section .text'
is2_exit.s:6: Error: no such instruction: `global _start'
is2_exit.s:13: Error: junk `h' after expression
```

It seems that the `.intel_syntax` is not considered at all. What's wrong?

Comment: How about if you use `.data`, `.text`, `.global _start` and `0x80`?

Comment: The `intel_syntax` does not apply to directives, especially since there is no single intel syntax. They are different in each assembler.

Comment: @Michael yes, you are right! If you want to write an answer, I will choose it.

Comment: @Jester I didn't know it. By changing the directives syntax it gives no errors in fact.

Comment: I'd recommend something else for doing assembler programming. gas is not that well suited for this. Try [yasm](http://yasm.tortall.net), [fasm](http://flatassembler.net) or [nasm](http://www.nasm.us) instead.

Comment: Is there one file out there using Intel syntax which *can* compile using current versions of both NASM and GAS (via .intel_syntax)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using NASM syntax for some of the directives, as well as a hexadecimal literal. You need to change those to use GNU AS syntax.

Instead of `section name` you should use `.section name` (with a leading dot). In the case of `.section .text` and `.section .data` you can simplify those into `.text` and `.data`.

Similarly, `global symbol` should be `.global symbol` (or `.globl symbol`) in GNU AS syntax.

---

Regarding hexadecimal literals, the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Integers.html) has this to say:

> A hexadecimal integer is '0x' or '0X' followed by one or more hexadecimal digits chosen from `0123456789abcdefABCDEF'.

So `80h` should be written `0x80` (or `0X80`).