# Does linux "as" assembler support intel format assembly language?

Tags: linux, assembly, syntax, format, intel

The default assembler under linux is "as". I know gdb supports disassembly using both AT&T and Intel syntax.

My question is, I know "as" supports AT&T format, does it support Intel format? E.g. I've "b.s" file

```
.global _start
_start:
mov ax,0
```

Then

```
as b.s
b.s: Assembler messages:
b.s:3: Error： too many memory references for `mov'
```

How to make "as" compile this .s file?
Thanks.

Comment: Add `.intel_syntax noprefix` to the top of the assembly file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9347909/6664886) for some pointers of gcc/gas with Intel syntax.

I personally have used NASM for the occasional pure assembly projects (which is Intel syntax native) or Intel's icc for C programs with inlines.

Comment: Thanks, I've added ".intel_syntax noprefix" in my .s file to solve this problem.