how do I turn AT&T syntax into intel syntax?
In AT&T syntax you can do something like asm("mov %%eax, %0\n\t":"=r" (a[0])); but not in intel syntax.
I want to translate this AT&T syntax to intel syntax, it gets the cpu brand name and print it.
int a[10];
void brandString(int eaxValues)
{
    if (eaxValues == 1) {
    __asm__("mov $0x80000002 , %eax\n\t");
    }
    else if (eaxValues == 2) {
        __asm__("mov $0x80000003 , %eax\n\t");
    }
    else if (eaxValues == 3) {
        __asm__("mov $0x80000004 , %eax\n\t");
    }
    __asm__("cpuid\n\t");
    __asm__("mov %%eax, %0\n\t":"=r" (a[0]));
    __asm__("mov %%ebx, %0\n\t":"=r" (a[1]));
    __asm__("mov %%ecx, %0\n\t":"=r" (a[2]));
    __asm__("mov %%edx, %0\n\t":"=r" (a[3]));
    printf("%s", &a[0]);
}

void getCpuID()
{
    __asm__("xor %eax , %eax\n\t");
    __asm__("xor %ebx , %ebx\n\t");
    __asm__("xor %ecx , %ecx\n\t");
    __asm__("xor %edx , %edx\n\t");
    printf("Brand string is ");
    brandString(1);
    brandString(2);
    brandString(3);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    getCpuID();
}

and, so far, I have done:
char a[10];
void brandString(int eaxValues)
{
    if (eaxValues == 1) {
        __asm {
            mov eax, 0x80000002
        }
    }
    else if (eaxValues == 2) {
        __asm {
            mov eax, 0x80000003
        }
    }
    else if (eaxValues == 3) {
        __asm {
            mov eax, 0x80000004
        }
    }
    
    __asm {
         cpuid
         mov    a[0], eax
         mov    a[1], ebx  
         mov    a[2], ecx  
         mov    a[3], edx 
    }
    
    printf("%s", &a[0]);
}


void getCpuID() {
     __asm {
            xor eax, eax
            xor ebx, ebx
            xor ecx, ecx
            xor edx, edx
        }
    printf("Brand string is ");
    brandString(1);
    brandString(2);
    brandString(3);
    printf("\n");
}

but obviously you can not do mov a[0], eax so I'm stuck, I do not know how to do it.

Quoting the docs: Do not expect a sequence of asm statements to remain perfectly consecutive after compilation, even when you are using the volatile qualifier. If certain instructions need to remain consecutive in the output, put them in a single multi-instruction asm statement.  Which means that just because you set eax to a specific value in one asm statement, you can't assume it will still be there for the second (especially when intervening statements call printf which USES eax).  Consider using the functions in cpuid.h.

Probably related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347909/can-i-use-intel-syntax-of-x86-assembly-with-gcc - but why ?

Or is your "actual" question how to convert gcc inline assembler to msvc style inline assembler ?

    unsigned int regs[4];
    char brand[49] = {0};

    // Inline assembly to call CPUID with given eax value and store results in regs
    #define cpuid(eax_val, regs) \
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( \
    "cpuid" \
    : "=a" (regs[0]), "=b" (regs[1]), "=c" (regs[2]), "=d" (regs[3]) \
    : "a" (eax_val) \
    );

    // Call CPUID with 0x80000002, 0x80000003, and 0x80000004 and store the brand string
    cpuid(0x80000002, regs);
    memcpy(brand, regs, sizeof(regs));

    cpuid(0x80000003, regs);
    memcpy(brand + 16, regs, sizeof(regs));

    cpuid(0x80000004, regs);
    memcpy(brand + 32, regs, sizeof(regs));

    printf("  Brand string is: %s\n\n", brand);

The characteristics of this code are:
Macro for CPUID:
    Defines a macro cpuid to encapsulate the cpuid instruction. This macro takes eax value and a register array as parameters.

Direct Memory Copy:
    Uses memcpy to copy the results of cpuid into the brand array directly.

Single Loop for Concatenation:
    Calls cpuid with 0x80000002, 0x80000003, and 0x80000004 values and copies each result into different parts of the brand array.

Local Variables:
    Uses local arrays regs and brand for storing the register values and the resulting brand string.

Output at End:
    The brand string is fully constructed before printing, ensuring that the entire string is output at once.

Summary of Differences
Structure:
    The first snippet uses a function with conditional statements and inline assembly directly in C code.
    The second snippet uses a macro to encapsulate the cpuid calls, making the code cleaner and more modular.

Memory Management:
    The first snippet uses a global array a, while the second snippet uses local arrays regs and brand.

Printing:
    The first snippet prints parts of the brand string within the loop.
    The second snippet constructs the full brand string first and then prints it.

Efficiency and Readability:
    The second snippet is more efficient and readable due to the use of a macro and direct memory copying.

Overall, the second code snippet is more elegant and efficient, with better memory management and cleaner code structure.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Unlike the bot, I really like the answer. You may want to clarify that a) the way you've written the inline assembly makes use of gcc facilities (how to map arguments/return values for assembler instructions to variables in the C code), that b) with this you sidestep any "need" for distinguishing between AT&T / Intel syntax for the specific case of the cpuid instruction, and c) that the original question is unclear, in the sense that it doesn't explain why the expectation there is to use Intel syntax with gcc inline assembly.
