# GNU assembler syntax for IN and OUT instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly, att, ioports

I am writing an inline assembly code to read Real-Time clock. I am loading the register number(4) to be read to 'dl' and loading this to port 0x70. I am trying to read this register value(4) into al. For more information - [RTC](http://wiki.osdev.org/RTC)

```
asm(
"mov $4, %%dl;"
"out 0x70, %%dl;"
"in %%al, 0x71;"
:
:
:"%al","%dl"
);
```

I am getting the below error message on compiling the c file that contains this code.

> Assembler messages:
>
> Error: operand size mismatch for 'out'
>
> Error: operand size mismatch for `in'

The assembler version : GNU assembler version 2.26.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1

Can someone please point out the issue?

Comment: At a guess, the error messages are due to not having a `$` in front of the constants.  That said, if you want your asm to output a value, you need to have an output parameter (after the first colon).  And I'd be surprised if you could use `in` or `out` while running Ubuntu.  And aren't you supposed to `cli` before reading RTC? And if you are building 16bit code, I'm not sure using the 64bit compiler is going to work.  And if you are trying to read the RTC at boot time, how about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46074535/2189500).

Comment: AT&T syntax generally has the destination on the right side. I would expect that for the IN and OUT instructions as well. `IN 0x71,%%al`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd You can use `in` and `out` after giving yourself the right to do so using the `iopl()` or `ioperm()` system calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of problems. First, both `in` and `out` can only operate on the A register (`al`, `ax`, `eax`, `rax`). Second, the operand order is wrong and third, immediates have to be prefixed with `$` in AT&T syntax. In plain assembly, your code should look like this:

```
mov $4,%al
out %al,$0x70
in  $0x71,%al
```

So your corrected assembly would be

```
asm(
"movb $4, %%al;"
"outb %%al, $0x70;"
"inb $0x71, %%al;"
:
:
:"%al"
);
```

Note that I have added explicit size suffixes to help clang assemble this code. I recommend you to further alter this code to use correct extended inline assembly:

```
unsigned char result;
volatile asm("outb %1,$0x70; inb $0x71, %0" : "=a"(result) : "a"((char)4));
```

This could make gcc generate slightly better code. For example, it allows gcc to inline this code.

Furthermore, you could consider using the `inb()` and `outb()` macros from `<sys/io.h>` to avoid inline assembly altogether. This is typically a very good thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Can you please point me to a comprehensive guide on AT&T syntax for inline assembly so that I avoid such syntactical errors?

Comment: You should also get a good instruction set reference, which will tell you that there is no out instruction with dl as the source. I use the Intel manual (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm).